# bootstrap nav not collapsing on small screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Not sure if I am even doing this right

```
#navigation.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
.container
    .navbar-header
        %button.navbar-toggle.collapsed{"aria-expanded" => "false", "data-target" => "#navbar-1", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :type => "button"}
            %span.sr-only Toggle
            %span.icon-bar
            %span.icon-bar
            %span.icon-bar
        %b= link_to "TITLE", root_path, class: 'navbar-brand'
    #full-screen-nav
        .navbar-collapse.collapse#navbar-1
            %ul.nav.navbar-nav
                %li Item 1...
```

Right now when the screen size width is less than 640, all items (item1, item2,...) simply disappear, leaving only TITLE in the navbar.

I thought `navbar-collapse.collapse` is suppose to collapse those item into some sort of drop down? or did I misunderstood what this class is suppose to do?

How can I fix it so that the items will reappear on smaller screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missing the `button.navbar-toggle.collapsed` on your `.navbar-header`

This button will show/hide your menu.

Check the example bootrap made for navbar [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Your code should look something like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbytcy1x/)

Comment: I've added the code, and now an icon has appeared. But when I click on it, no drop-down menu shows. What's happening now?

Comment: @user3277633  do  you have the 'data-target' on the button and set the id of the div to collapse?

Comment: Yeah I've edited the code above, pleas let me know if it's correct! it does not work still

Comment: your `.navbar-collapse.collapse#navbar-1` should be at the same level as your .navbar-header

Comment: fixed that but it does not seem to work still. Interestingly it works on jsfiddle. Am I missing something here that's not bootstrap related? http://jsfiddle.net/x19gn9hp/

Comment: did you check your console. It might be because some resources are not loaded properly. Check if you have your jquery file loaded successfully.

Comment: did a quick check just now, it appears that jquery is loaded properly

Comment: no errors appeared on the console when you click the button?

Comment: oh my god im an idiot. A few days ago I wrote in a test code that removes the full navigation on certain screen size, and I've been testing it on that specific screen size. Thanks for all your help though!!!